# Who is the boy referred to in the title of the movie "The Boy in the Striped Pyjamas"?

Tags: title, the-boy-in-the-striped-pyjamas

The movie **The Boy in the Striped Pyjamas** features two boys.

1. Schmuel, a Jewish inmate
2. Bruno, a Nazi Commandant's son

Who exactly is the title referring to?

Comment: Although there is a definite correct answer to this question (as posted below), there is also nothing wrong with having a little bit of ambiguity in the title; it can add to the poignancy of the film to think of questions like this after watching.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The title refers to ***Schmuel***. The film is told from Bruno's point of view, and he sees the titular Boy in the Striped Pyjamas.

In the film, Bruno refers to the prison uniforms as Pyjamas multiple times. In fact, he even asks Schmuel about it:

> Bruno: Can I ask you something?
>   Bruno: Why do you people wear pyjamas all day?
>   Schmuel: They’re not pyjamas.